# Given $0<x<1$ and $0 \le z \le 1-x$, why is $\sqrt{z+x}-(1-\sqrt{x})\sqrt{\frac{z}{1-x}} \le \sqrt{x}$?

Tags: inequality

This seems true, but I have so far failed to prove it. Any clever estimates I could use?

Answer (score 3):

Let $x=\sin^2 \alpha$ and $z=\cos^2\beta$, where $0<\alpha,\beta<\frac{\pi}{2}$. Then the condition $0\le z\le1-x$ is equivalent to $\alpha\le\beta$ and the inequality becomes
$$ \sqrt{\sin^2\alpha+\cos^2\beta}\le(1-\sin\alpha)\frac{\cos\beta}{\cos\alpha}+\sin\alpha $$
which is equivalent to
$$ \cos^2\beta\le \frac{(1-\sin\alpha)^2}{\cos^2\alpha}\cos^2\beta+2\frac{(1-\sin\alpha)\sin\alpha}{\cos\alpha}\cos\beta$$
or
$$ \frac{\cos^2\alpha-(1-\sin\alpha)^2}{\cos^2\alpha}\cos\beta\le2\frac{(1-\sin\alpha)\sin\alpha}{\cos\alpha} \tag{1}$$
Noting that 
$$ \cos^2\alpha-(1-\sin\alpha)^2=2\sin\alpha-2\sin^2\alpha=2\sin\alpha(1-\sin\alpha)>0 $$
Thus (1) becomes
$$ \frac{2\sin\alpha(1-\sin\alpha)}{\cos^2\alpha}\cos\beta\le2\frac{(1-\sin\alpha)\sin\alpha}{\cos\alpha} $$
which is equivalent to
$$ \cos\beta\le\cos\alpha. $$
This is true because $\alpha\le\beta$. Thus the inequality is true. Done

Comment: why downvote? What is the reason?

Comment: Thanks! (Wasn't me who downvoted.) This helps me a lot! I wonder whether there is a simpler way to show this... ;-)

Comment: @blinry, you are welcome.